# Split Java ArrayList into equal parts

Tags: java

I have seen this question asked a few times, but I do not entirely understand the solutions provided.
Below is a bit of code I came up with for splitting up an arraylist into five parts. I have tested and changed the array size from 0 to 16 and it works fine.

I am sure there is a "better" way of doing this, so I would like to see what others think.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayList.add("A");//1
    arrayList.add("B");//2
    arrayList.add("C");//3
    arrayList.add("D");//4
    arrayList.add("E");//5
    arrayList.add("F");//6
    arrayList.add("G");//7
    arrayList.add("H");//8
    arrayList.add("I");//9
    arrayList.add("J");//10
    arrayList.add("K");//11
    arrayList.add("L");//12
    arrayList.add("M");//13
    arrayList.add("N");//14
    arrayList.add("O");//15
    arrayList.add("P");//16
    arrayList.add("X");//17

    int i1 = (int) Math.ceil(arrayList.size()/5.0);

    List<String> sublist = new ArrayList<String>();
    int x=0;
    for(int p=0; p<i1; p++)
    {
        if(arrayList.size()>=(x+5))
        {
            sublist = new ArrayList<String>(arrayList.subList(x, x+5));
            x+=5;
        }
        else
            sublist = new ArrayList<String>(arrayList.subList(x, arrayList.size()));
        for(String slist : sublist)
        {
            System.out.println("i:"+slist);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems like you are mixing up the number of segments and the number of elements per segment. In your example, both are the same, so the result is correct, but in other cases it will not be. For instance, `i1` is created as the number of elements per segment, with the number of segments being hard-coded as `5.0`. Then, in the loop, you treat `i1` as the number of segments, while the number of elements per segment is hard-coded as `5`. Mistakes like this will be easier to spot if you use properly named variables, like `numSegments` or `segmentSize` instead of `i1` or integer constants.

Also:

- no need to wrap the sublists into `new ArrayList`
- you can just count by increments according to the number of elements per sublist instead of using two counters, for the current sublist and the offset
- you could use a ternary `... ? ... : ...` instead of that `if/else`

How about this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++) {
        arrayList.add(String.valueOf(i));
    }

    int size = 5;
    for (int start = 0; start < arrayList.size(); start += size) {
        int end = Math.min(start + size, arrayList.size());
        List<String> sublist = arrayList.subList(start, end);
        System.out.println(sublist);
    }
}
```

Here, `size` is the number of elements in each sublist. So instead of counting the segment of the list and increasing a second counter by 5 each time, you can just increase the first counter by five in the third argument of the `for` loop. Also, you can use the result of `subList` directly, without passing it to a constructor first. And you can get rid of the `if-else` by using `min` to determine the end index.

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
[15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[20, 21, 22]
```

If instead of sublists with 5 elements you wanted five sublists, then use this (same result for the given example, but different for other list sizes):

```
int size = (int) Math.ceil(arrayList.size() / 5.0);
```

Comment: How to split array list in to equal parts of we dont know the chunk size (5 in your case) but we know the number of parts we want to make. e.g. how to split above 23 items in to 4 parts (dont know how many items should go to each part). My real use case is to split big file in to number of files

Comment: @user1191081 Maybe I'm missing something, but you just divide? 23 items to 4 parts -> 23/4 == 5.something -> 6 parts, i.e. `ceil(numItems/numParts)`.

Comment: Why the simultaneous downvote to all three answers?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Java 8 [`Collectors.groupingBy(Function<T,K> classifier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) to do a list partitioning. What it does it simply divides an input list (e.g. `List<String>`) and divides it to a collection of n-size lists (e.g. `Collection<List<String>>`). Take a look at following code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Partition {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","X");

        final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
        final int size = 5;

        final Collection<List<String>> partitioned = list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter.getAndIncrement() / size))
                .values();

        partitioned.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

We starts with `list` containing 17 elements. Our goal is to divide this list into lists of size 5 at maximum, no matter how many elements input list contains. What we do is we group all elements using a key computed as `counter / size`, so it generates a map like:

```
{0=[A,B,C,D,E], 1=[F,G,H,I,J], 2=[K,L,M,N,O], 3=[P,X]}
```

We are only interested in values of this map, so calling `Map.values()` method returns:

```
[[A,B,C,D,E], [F,G,H,I,J], [K,L,M,N,O], [P,X]]
```

And you can display these lists one by one with `partitioned.forEach(System.out::println)`

```
[A, B, C, D, E]
[F, G, H, I, J]
[K, L, M, N, O]
[P, X]
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Neat. But is `Map.values()` guaranteed to return those in sorted order?